# how do I change the date/time format in the top panel in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, indicator, desktop-environments

I searched for this answer and have tried dconf-editor and gconf-editor per instructions and nothing changes the top panel time.  When I change the format using the system settings menu it does NOT change the values shown under dconf-editor.  The system settings menu doesn't' allow a custom string for display format.  Obviously these values are stored some place else.  Anybody know WHERE?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use a tweak tool like `gnome-tweak-tool` or `unity-tweak-tool` for this. I haven't poked around much in the date area, but it might be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the time in the top panel then on time and date settings in the window that opens, click on clock tab in the next window, their you will find several setting that can be change.

Comment: I want to use a custom datetime format,not the limited choices given by system settings.  In my case I want to display Mon 12 Apr 14 17:38:23 hrs CDT